# Why Do Radio Buttons Require: name="radios" For CSS3 Recognition

Tags: html, css, radio-button

Trying to edit the appearance of two radio buttons and all is well if the markup is as follows:

```
<ul class="radioHorizontal">
    <li class="spaceRight">
        <input id="radioYes" type="radio" name="radios" checked>
        <label for="radioYes">Yes</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="radioNo" type="radio" name="radios">
        <label for="radioNo">No</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, if I remove: `name="radios"` and leave everything else untouched, inside or outside of my `ul` list the buttons can never be unchecked and my desired effect is broken.

```
My CSS3 is as follows:

    input[ type = radio ]
{
    display:none; 
}

input[ type = radio ] + label
{
    padding: 4px 12px;
    background-color: rgba( 40, 40, 40, 1 );

    border: 2px solid rgb( 30, 30, 30 );
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba( 125, 125, 125, 0.75 );
}

input[ type = radio ]:checked + label
{ 
    background-image: none;
    background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.4 );
}
```

I have no problem using name="radios" unless some unforeseen, bizarrely specific circumstances prohibit it I am just curious why this is required for the CSS3 to work.

Comment: It doesn't need that specific name, but if you want them to be linked to each other, they need to have the same name attribute.

Comment: The CSS has nothing to do with this, it's the way grouping with HTML radio buttons works.

Comment: @kalley thank you, such a dumb overlook on my behalf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't affect the CSS at all, but the name is required to group them. Only one radiobutton of a group can be selected, and the others are deselected automatically. If you don't give them a name, each of them is in their own group.

Comment: What a stupid overlook on my behalf. I will accept this answer the second I can.